# Multiple dynamic tables and bind with same data source

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a master table which is shown as GridView. The user can create a sublist and move selected rows from master table to the newly created sublist. The user can create multiple sublist. Sublist actually nothing but a column value in the database table. But for user its a separate list of rows, so I need to show the lists on front-end in separate tables. 
I could do with one master and one child i.e. selecting row from master table and add into a child table view (both asp.net GridView)

But I am at complete loss of idea as to how to create multiple copy of child lists dynamically (number of child is not fixed) and bind them to same data source filtered with one column value.

The tech stack is asp.net / JS/ JQuery and can learn and work with AngularJS a bit.

Can someone please point me to right direction?

And a humble request not to flame. I haven't tried because I really don't know where to start. As I said, I could do with one master-child table but not one master multiple child.